# Magento 2 : After Data Migration(Indexer issue)

Tags: indexing, data-migration, data-migration-tool

After successfully migrated from Magento 1.x to 2.x I am getting issues with **Indexer**, Check below screen.

(I need to Show products on frontend So, re-indexing is must)

[image: Please see this error when try to do reindexing]

Please Help Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Most probably you imported some tier prices for at least a product for a website that does not exist

Comment: Ok then what should i do to remove this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, most probably you imported some tier prices for at least a product for a website that does not exist.

To fix this you have to identify the rows in the table `catalog_product_entity_tier_price` that have in the column  `website_id` a value that is not present in the table `store_website`.

A rough query could be

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    catalog_product_entity_tier_price tier
WHERE 
    website_id NOT IN (
        SELECT website_id FROM store_website
    )
```

I'm sure this is not optimized but it should work.
To delete the rows if any just change in the query above `SELECT *` with `DELETE`.
This is not tested and I might be wrong so please backup your db first.

If there are rows and you delete them, try reindexing again.